# How To Set A Value To An Object In An (Actionlistener) Save Method?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, actionlistener

I have an `actionListener` below that works fine:

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{demandasController.saveNew}" ... />
```

The `saveNew` method is:

```
public void saveNew(ActionEvent event) {

    Situacao situacao = new Situacao();
    situacao.setIdSituacao(4);

    this.getSelected().setSituacao(situacao);

    super.saveNew(event);
}
```

If I use the code above, it works just fine. But if I try...

```
public void saveNew(ActionEvent event) {

Situacao situacao = new Situacao();

Date currentDate = new Date();

if (this.getSelected().getDtInicial().after(currentDate)) {
    situacao.setIdSituacao(4);
} else {
    situacao.setIdSituacao(5);
}

this.getSelected().setSituacao(situacao);

super.saveNew(event);
}
```

...it returns a [NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

Does anyone knows why this is happening and/or how can I fix it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Debug and check the value of `this.getSelected().getDtInicial()` I would take a stab and guess that's returning null, you are then trying to operate on a null thus causing a null pointer

Comment: Luke Garrigan, I knew it was something very simple I was missing, you're right! Thanks!

Comment: Please, post your explanation as an answer so I can accept it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the error message: `NullPointerException` and from the initial code working but the second lot not working, the following code must be returning null.

```
this.getSelected().getDtInicial()
```

then the `.after(currentDate)` is an operation on a null which causes the null pointer.

Comment: I wasn't focusing on `this.getSelected().getDtInicial()`, but in the object to set. Thank you so much!!